# display html tags using jquery

Tags: jquery

I got following json:

```
{"results":[{"id":"1","title":"Hello","content":"Hello<br>world"}]}
```

the data can be successfully displayed in the following way

```
$('<td class="a">').html(res.id),
$('<td class="b">').html(res.title),
$('<td class="c">').html(res.content),
```

The only problem is that I want to display `<br>` tag as well. Is there any function in jquery which can help me to display html tag as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use [`text`](http://api.jquery.com/text/#text2):

> We need to be aware that this method escapes the string provided as
>   necessary so that it will render correctly in HTML. To do so, it calls
>   the DOM method `.createTextNode()`, does not interpret the string as
>   HTML.

```
$('<td class="a">').text(res.id);
$('<td class="b">').text(res.title);
$('<td class="c">').text(res.content);
```